# join multiple tables in CakePHP and retrive data

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, cakephp-2.0

**Updated Question**

I am trying to Join Multiple tables in CakePHP and retrieve their data.
I have created my Model but not getting relevant result.

Below is my Table Structure.

```
Fields needed :
    Equipment Name
    Equipment Description
    Equipment Type name according to Equipment id
    Equipment Type Sizes names according to Type id
    Sizes Stock.
```

**Model:Equipment.php**

```
class Equipment extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'equipments';
    var $name = 'Equipment';
    public $cacheQueries = false;

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Sizes' => array(
            'className' => 'EquipmentSize',
            'foreignKey' => 'equipment_id'

        )
    );
}
```

**Model:EquipmentSizes .php**

```
class EquipmentSizes extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'equipment_sizes';
    var $name = 'EquipmentSizes';
    public $cacheQueries = false;
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Equipment' => array(
            'className' => 'Equipment',
            'foreignKey' => 'equipment_id',
            'fields' => array('id', 'sizes')
        )
    );
 }
```

**Model:EquipmentType.php**

```
class EquipmentType extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'equipment_types';
    var $name = 'EquipmentType';
    public $cacheQueries = false;

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Sizes' => array(
            'className' => 'EquipmentTypesSize',
            'foreignKey' => 'equipment_type_id'
        )
    );
}
```

**Model:EquipmentTypesSizes.php**

```
class EquipmentTypesSizes extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'equipment_types_sizes';
    var $name = 'EquipmentTypesSizes';
    public $cacheQueries = false;
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'EquipmentType' => array(
            'className' => 'EquipmentType',
            'foreignKey' => 'equipment_type_id',
            'fields' => array('id', 'sizes')
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: your issue is database architecture, not CakePHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten the foreign keys on some of your models (Equipment.php, EquipmentType.php) that have hasToMany relationship. Correct your models first then try to query an equipment and you can see there the associated models of Equipment. You can then base your conditions to that.

**Updated - Equipment.php**

```
class Equipment extends AppModel {
   public $useTable = 'equipments';
   var $name = 'Equipment';
   public $cacheQueries = false;

   public $hasMany = array(
     'Sizes' => array(
        'className' => 'EquipmentSize',
        'foreignKey' => 'equipment_id'

    ),
    'EquipmentType' => array(
        'className' => 'EquipmentType',
        'foreignKey' => 'equipment_id'

    )
 );
```

}

**EquipmentSizes.php** is correct.

**Updated - EquipmentType.php**

```
class EquipmentType extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'equipment_types';
    var $name = 'EquipmentType';
    public $cacheQueries = false;

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Sizes' => array(
            'className' => 'EquipmentTypesSize',
            'foreignKey' => 'equipment_type_id'
        )
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Equipment' => array(
            'className' => 'Equipment',
            'foreignKey' => 'equipment_id'
        )
    );
}
```

**EquipmentTypesSizes.php** is correct.

Comment: thankx . i have updated my code with your suggesstion but problem is same.. i have updated my question also here. and DB also.. please ..

Comment: @PuzzledBoy please update your question, add there the query you userd and its output so we can help you debug it.

Comment: @PuzzledBoy, I have updated here the answer :)